# jquery to check If a div has a specific content

Tags: jquery

```
$("#thinker01").click( function() {
$("#info").html("323");
    if ($("#info").html == "323"){  //doesn't work - how to say this?
        $("#imgOk").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Without `if` - the fourth line works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($("#info").html() == "323")
```

Notice the `()` around the html function which is what is actually invoking it. Otherwise you are using it as a property and there's no such property.

Answer (score 2):

[html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a function and must be called.

You may use this :

```
if ($("#info").html() == "323")
```

Comment: I believe you missed the `()`